# How to allow apache read files created by another user on cpanel

Tags: apache, cpanel, centos6, whm

I have project on CPANEL, where another application creates files by another user.
And when I want to access to these files, apache return 404 error.
Apache log:

> Caught race condition abuser. attacker: 502, victim: 0 open file owner: 0, open file:

It means that apache cannot read files created by another user.
How can I fix it? I have an access to WHM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer [there](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/EA/Symlink+Race+Condition+Protection)
It was some patch for apache in WHM. It prevents access to files that the user does not own.